# ERROR TypeError: .indexOf is not a function

Tags: angular

I trying to create a function which I can modify the boolean value of a selected role with checkbox.
this is the function:

```
changeRole(roleName){
    let roleEdit = this.selectedUser.roles.filter(roleEdit => roleEdit.indexOf(roleName) >= 0)[0];
    let roleE = {
      "title": roleEdit,
      "value": false
    }
      if(roleEdit == roleName){
        if(roleE.value == false){
          roleE.value = true;

        }else{
          roleE.value = false;
        }
      }
  }
```

I have defined roles with an array of string in the user model:

```
export class User {
  public constructor (
    public firstName: string,
    public lastName:string,
    public roles: string[],
    .....
}
```

the pb is that I have this message and I didn't know how to fix it :
**ERROR TypeError: roleEdit.indexOf is not a function
        at Array.filter ()**

can someone helps me??

Here's the content of the `selectedUser` object:

```
{
    "id": "5ac91784295a3c2824b025e3",
    "firstName": "yasmin",
    "lastName": "yasmin",
    "login": "yasmin",
    "pwd": "168d3c263aa44687fc3f8e78ad56d869",
    "email": "yasmin.yasmin@gmail.com",
    "cin": "111111111",
    "address": {
        "country": "aaaaaa",
        "city": "aaaaaaa",
        "zipCode": "111111",
        "street": "aaaaaaa"
    },
    "gender": null,
    "telephone": "1212121212",
    "roles": [{
        "title": "employé",
        "value": false
    }, {
        "title": "authorizer",
        "value": false
    }, {
        "title": "validateur",
        "value": true
    }, {
        "title": "admin",
        "value": true
    }],
    "dateTime": "2018-04-07 20:09:55"
}
```

Comment: What happens when you execute `console.log(JSON.stringify(this.selectedUser))`?

Comment: it gives me the selected user with his details,  and of course the list of his roles with the value (true or false)

Comment: Don't describe what you get. Post it.

Comment: OK. So, does the roles array look like an array of strings to you? It's not. It's an array of objects. Each object having a title (string), and a value (boolean). Objects don't have an indexOf() method. You class User doesn't describe the actual structure of a User.

Comment: but when I click on roles it shows (property) User.roles: string[]

Comment: Because you defined the class that way. But the class definition doesn't reflect the reality. That's what I told you already in my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

Selected user is an object containing array of roles so you can filter roles, but element role is an object so you must match title. Hope that helps.

```
let roleEdit = this.selectedUser.roles.filter(role => role.title == roleName);
```

You will probably get multiple values because filter returns an array so you can check length and get first in you want to.

```
if(roleEdit.length) {
  let roleToEdit = roleEdit[0];
  // do stuff
}
```